# How to make green suit completely invisible?

Tags: after-effects, chromakey

I use keylight in After effects to remove my green suit, but it leaves ghost like stuff on my video. How do I completely remove it? You can see my hands do not match the color of the background from the exactly the same video.

It is strange that I cannot find tutorials for such basic questions.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post a clip of your original footage before keying?

Comment: this answer and tutorial may help https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25635/what-are-some-best-camera-settings-for-recording-for-chroma-keying-and-which-col/25659#25659